# In Rails Routes redirect controller action to root?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a root path in my routes file:

```
root 'games#index'
```

The problem is that if anyone goes to: http://domain.com/games it doesn't show the root, thus we're creating two urls for the same page.

Is there a way to change any hit to http://domain.com/games to http://domain.com?

I'd rather not fiddle around with a `before_filter` in the application controller if there's a nice way to do it in the routes folder.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to just set up a redirect.

`map.redirect('/games','/')`

Although, your problem is really that the `/games` route shouldn't be there in in the first place.

Remove the catchall route at the bottom of your `routes.rb` file, and this won't even be a problem.

Comment: What Jamie suggested about removing the route from routes.rb. Then just avoid having any of your code link to the `/games` route, you can use the `root_path` helper method.

Comment: Hi guys, so I have:

map.resources :games
map.root, :controller => 'games', :action => 'index

The thing is, I need show, create, new, destroy for games, but the index should always be the root path.  

I tried the redirect, but I get this error:
No route matches "/"

Is there a way to map.resources :games, but not the index?

Comment: Also, my reason for needing this isn't because I'm linking to it per say, but I have a permanent redirect from a different domain that when redirecting, passes in the URL as domain.com/games instead of the root.

if ENV["RAILS_ENV"] != 'development' && request.env['HTTP_HOST'] != CURRENT_DOMAIN
        request.parameters[:host] = CURRENT_DOMAIN
        perm_redirect_to url_for(request.parameters)
      end

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with sessions. I wanted to expose /sessions for login and logout, but since an invalid password leaves you at /sessions, I wanted a graceful way to deal with a user re-submitting that URL as a GET (e.g. by typing Ctrl-L, ). This works for me on Rails 3:

```
resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
match '/sessions' => redirect('/login')
match '/login', :to => 'sessions#new'
```

I think your code would look something like this:

```
resources :games, :only => [:new, :edit, :create, :destroy]
match '/games' => redirect('/')
```

Comment: `match '/games' => redirect('/'), :via => :get`

Answer (score 2):

`routes.rb`:

```
  root 'games#index'
```

In controller:

```
  def index
    redirect_to root_path if request.env['PATH_INFO'] === '/games'
    @games = Game.all
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

As of the current version of Rails (3.2.9), this is how I achieved the same result:

```rb
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  # ...
  # declare the redirect first so it isn't caught by the default
  # resource routing
  match '/games' => redirect('/')
  # ...
  resources :games
  # ...
  root :to => 'games#index'
end
```